# How to receive selected location's geo coordinates?

Tags: location, botframework, bing-maps

How do I extract geo coordinates from user's selected location?

As far as I know BotBuilder-Location allows only to extract information such as place.streetAddress, place.locality, place.region, place.postalCode, place.country. But I am interested in receiving geo coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Place class has a GetGeoCoordinates function that you can use to get its coordinates. Here is the source code: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/blob/c4bdfa32c7190e92fc38ec02c6887edcace2dcf5/CSharp/BotBuilderLocation/Extensions.cs

Here is a sample (see the last function method), it gets the address from the place, use the GetGeoCoordinates function to get the coordinates from the place. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/blob/master/CSharp/BotBuilderLocation.Sample/Controllers/MessagesController.cs